# How to allow specific words using javax.validation.constraints.Pattern?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I would like to use javax.validation.constraints.Pattern for validation. The text should not be none or others.

Allowed Examples:

- something
- word

NOT allowed:

- none
- others

I am trying around but I dont catch my issue. Something like:

```
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "(^none)")
String  countryValue;
```

Thanks for your hint.

**UPDATE:**
As Anish said with the online regex validator, the regex `^(?!others|none)` should be correct. But Spring-MVC still denied. Is there a special syntax to be used? I give more code to have a bigger picture:

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping
public String post(@ModelAttribute @Valid DisclaimerFormDto disclaimerForm, BindingResult errors, ModelMap modelMap) {
    if(errors.hasErrors()) {
        errors.getAllErrors().forEach(System.out::println);
        return "redirect:/disclaimer";
    }
    return "redirect:/product";
}
```

**FormDto (with changes mentioned from Anish):**

```
@Data
@ToString
public class DisclaimerFormDto {
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?!others|none)")
    String  countryValue;
}
```

**Output of BindingResult:**

```
Field error in object 'disclaimerFormDto' on field 'countryValue': rejected value [none]; codes [Pattern.disclaimerFormDto.countryValue,Pattern.countryValue,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [disclaimerFormDto.countryValue,countryValue]; arguments []; default message [countryValue],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@59374db6,^(?!(none|others)$).*$]; default message [muss auf Ausdruck "^(?!(none|others)$).*$" passen]
```

Comment: Do you mean `something` literally?

Comment: `@Pattern(regexp = "^(something|word)$")`? `@Pattern(regexp = "^(?!(none|others)$).*$")`?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you so much. `^(?!(none|others)$).*$` works as I expected. If you dont mind to use it as answer with little explanation that would help others and I could accept it as correct answer. Thank you so much again. Espacially the part `)$).*$` I dont understand. If you have links to a good resource explaining it would be great, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this :

```
@NotNull
// @Pattern(regexp = "^(?!others|none)")
// updated to take any kind of string to match.
@Pattern(regexp = "^((?!(none|others)).)*$")  
private String countryValue;
```

**Check this regex example here: [^((?!(none|others)).)*$](https://regex101.com/r/xkzPzN/4)**

Test case 1 : String like "abc"

Screenshot :

[image]

Test case 2 : Strings like "abc others", "abc none", "none" or "words"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Your regex seems to be correct, but then the issue is somewhere else. I updated my question. Maybe you have a glue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Anish, just seen that the answer of  Wiktor Stribiżew is the correct one.

Comment: @MichaelHegner There was an issue with regex. Now, I tried with this regex it should work as expected. I have updated my answer

Comment: My case is just to exclude 'none' or 'others', which are values in select boxes. So I am not expecting long text, just defined words.